# In tensorflow, How to compute mean for each columns of a batch generated from a csv that has NaNs in multiple columns?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets

I am reading in a csv in batches and each batch has nulls in various place. I dont want to use tensorflow transform as it requires loading the entire data in memory. Currently i cannot ignore the NaNs present in each column while computing means if i am to try to do it for the entire batch at once. I can loop through each column and then find the mean per columns that way but that seems to be an inelegant solution.

Can somebody help in finding the right way to compute the mean per column of a csv batch that has NaNs present in multiple columns. Also, `[1,2,np.nan]` should produce 1.5 not 1.

Comment: `numpy.nanmean()`

Comment: I have to operate on tensors. Currently, my options are to wrap numpy.nanmean() in tf.py_function or to compute mean per column separately by explicitly using `tf.where` and then `tf.reduce_sum` and then diving by `tf.shape[-1] - tf.reduce_sum(tf.is_nan)`. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I am currently doing this: given tensor `a` of `rank 2` `tf.math.divide_no_nan(tf.reduce_sum(tf.where(tf.math.is_finite(a),a,0.),axis=0),tf.reduce_sum(tf.cast(tf.math.is_finite(a),tf.float32),axis=0))`

Let me know somebody has a better option